# Matlab: Solve symbolic equations derived from Matlab functions 'abs' and 'angle' (originally complex expressions)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have two equations and two unknowns. Trying to use symbolic output from matlab functions.

```
clear; clc;
J = 152e-6; % moment of inertia
W = 200*pi; % desired crossover freq
K = 0.1;    % torque constant
syms Ki Kp real
assume(Ki>0);
assume(Kp>0);
G = Ki/(i*W)*(1 + i*W/(Ki/Kp))*K/(i*W*J)
F = [abs(G) == 1; angle(G) == - 120*pi/180]
[Ki,Kp] = solve(F,Ki,Kp);
```

> Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.

Comment: Please ask an actual question. All of the details about PI controllers, transfer function, and crossover frequency are probably irrelevant to your actual problem and helping people understand your code.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the question, but there is still no explicit question. Questions usually have a question mark. If you ask another question in the future and want to gain reputation on this site it pays to be clear and very specific so that other's don't have to guess at what your problem might be. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

A solution can not be found because you are using inputs which are not precise. For example `-120*pi/180` is evaluated as a double which implies precision errors. Use `sym` instead.

I also rearranged your equations to one complex expression. Instead of `assume` you have to use `assumeAlso`, otherwise the assumption that `Ki` and `Kp` is real is overwritten.

```
J = sym('152e-6'); % moment of inertia
W = sym('200')*pi; % desired crossover freq
K = sym('0.1');    % torque constant
syms Ki Kp real
assumeAlso(Ki>0);
assumeAlso(Kp>0);
S=sym('-120')*pi/sym('180');
C=cos(S)+1i*sin(S);

F = Ki/(1i*W)*(1 + 1i*W/(Ki/Kp))*K/(1i*W*J)-C;
sol = solve(F,Ki,Kp);
```

Comment: You're overwriting your assumptions. If you apply more than one assumption to a variable you have to use [`assumeAlso`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumealso.html) or [logical operators with `assume`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html#bt07tt3-1). In this case: `syms Ki Kp real;` `assumeAlso(Ki>0);` `assumeAlso(Kp>0);` works.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Also, thanks for the tip concerning the question formulation. I will edit.

Comment: By further investigating the answer-code, even though a solution was provided by it, the main point was to let matlab provide a pair of equations and then use the output as input for the 'solve' function

Comment: @C1Ron: Where do you miss functionality with this solution? I don't see any advantage using two equations in this case.

Comment: You manipulated the original expression. Thus, one must have some math skills to obtain the expressions that you made. In my problem i was given a magnitude and an angle as solutions to a complex expression. So I wanted to use 'abs' for the magnitude and 'angle' for the angle, thus enabling me to find two unknowns from the resulting expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
clear; clc;
J = 152e-6;
W = 200*pi;
K = 0.1;
syms Ki Kp real
assumeAlso(Ki>0);
assumeAlso(Kp>0);
G = Ki/(i*W)*(1 + i*W/(Ki/Kp))*K/(i*W*J);
phi = -120*pi/180;
eq1 = abs(G);
eq1 = rewrite(eq1,'sqrt');
eq2 = angle(G);
eq2 = simplify(eq2);
sol = solve([eq1 == 1,eq2 == phi],Ki,Kp);
```

I found a solution.

'rewrite' and 'simplify', made the equations more managable for solve.